# how to displaying xml data in html page?

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

i am trying to read the xml file but somehow i am getting problem : xml data can't displayed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://data.bmkg.go.id/gempadirasakan.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Gempa");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  { 
  document.write("<tr><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Tanggal")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Magnitude")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  }
document.write("</table>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

how i can display it???

Comment: It works for me under IE8.

Answer (score -1):

Construct the *whole* markup as a string, and only after that, write in body:

```
var markup = "<table border='1'>";
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Gempa");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
  markup += ("<tr><td>");
  markup += (x[i].getElementsByTagName("Tanggal")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  markup += ("</td><td>");
  markup += (x[i].getElementsByTagName("Magnitude")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  markup += ("</td></tr>");
}
markup += ("</table>")
document.write(markup);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working fine try to load xml by the following

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://data.bmkg.go.id/gempadirasakan.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDocument=xmlhttp.responseText;
xmlDoc=document.createElement("div");
xmlDoc.innerHTML=xmlDocument;
document.write("<table border='1'>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Gempa");
//then your following code
document.write("</table>");
</script>
```

Comment: this coding display xml data surely. can you try it

Comment: i have try, but this coding not display xml data.
whether I can see your coding??